# Can't remote postgresql on centos7 with pgadmin

Tags: centos7, postgresql, remote

I was install postgresql95 on centos 7(in my server), but i can't remote the postgresql with pgadmin from my laptop. I have try any way, but still can't remote it.

I have done setup on postgresql.conf and pg_hba.conf

i changed this in postgresql.conf

```
#listen_addresses = '*'
```

and add this in pg_hba.conf

```
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0               trust
host    all             all             ::/0                    trust
```

I try to restart my postgresql

```
systemctl start postgresql-9.5
systemctl stop postgresql-9.5
```

But still can't remote it. I try to do something with my firewall like this

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public --add-port=5432/tcp
firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public --add-port=5432/udp
firewall-cmd --reload
```

It runs fine when I open port 80 to access my server, but it does not work properly for port 5432.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `#` from `#listen_addresses = '*'`. You have it commented out.

The line should look like:

`listen_addresses = '*'`